# MKPolyline with different colors in Objective c

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit, mkpolyline

How to draw multiple `MKPolyline` with different colors and patterns.

- I wanted to draw two `MKPolylines`
- one with blue color solid line
- second with red color dashed pattern

I am able to differentiate pattern but its not differentiating colors 
here is my code

```
-(MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[self.myPolyline class]])
    {

        MKPolylineRenderer *renderer1 = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc]initWithPolyline:overlay];
        UIColor *routeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        renderer1.strokeColor = routeColor;
        renderer1.lineWidth = 5;

        return renderer1;
    }
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[self.myDottedPolyline class]])
    {
        //sets the pattern to a line 2 points long followed by a 1 point gap.
        //renderer.lineDashPattern = @[@2, @1];

        MKPolylineRenderer *renderer2 = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc]initWithPolyline:overlay];
        UIColor *liveRouteColor = [UIColor redColor];
        renderer2.lineWidth = 7;
        renderer2.lineDashPattern = @[@20,@3];
        renderer2.strokeColor = liveRouteColor;

        return renderer2;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: How you are adding MKPolyline in your map can you add that code ?

Comment: [self.sampleMap addOverlay:self.myPolyline]; [self.sampleMap addOverlay:self. myDottedPolyline]

Comment: Ok now can you add screen shot what you get on your map ?

Comment: `renderer2.lineDashPattern = @[@20,@3];` this line may be creating long dash line i think you need to go with smaller dash like @2 or @5

Comment: i want long dashed pattern but it is plotting dotts

Comment: But Line is in blue color dot means something wrong in your code as here i can see dotted line with red color but in your screen shot its showing in blue. Have you change your code if yes please update your code here ?

Comment: no i havent changed color , dats my issue it is taking color of renderer 1 for both lines

Comment: and why you use 2 `if` condition in your code you can use `else if {}` over there may be thats also creating problem.

Comment: changed to else if still no result

Answer (score 0):

I am using below code to differentiate polyline colors and pattern , 
but it is printing **//Renderer 2 print**  renderer 2 executing only once.
after that it jumps on Renderer 1 again.

```
    -(MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
    {
       UIColor *BlueRoute = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:104/255.0f blue:163/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
       UIColor *redRoute = [UIColor colorWithRed:241/255.0f green:122/255.0f blue:6/255.0f alpha:1.0f];


        if ([overlay isMemberOfClass:[_myPolyline class]])
        {
            MKPolylineRenderer *renderer1 = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc]initWithPolyline:overlay];

                NSLog(@"Renderer : %@",renderer1);
                renderer1.lineWidth = 5;
                renderer1.path = (__bridge CGPathRef _Nullable)(self.myPolyline);
                [renderer1 createPath];
                [renderer1 invalidatePath];
                [renderer1 setNeedsDisplay];
                renderer1.strokeColor = BlueRoute;

                if (_myPolyline.isAccessibilityElement == TRUE)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Renderer Color : %@",renderer1);
                    renderer1.fillColor = BlueRoute;
                }

                return renderer1;


        }



        if ([overlay isMemberOfClass:[_myDottedPolyline class]] )
        {
            MKPolylineRenderer *renderer2 = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc]initWithPolyline:overlay];
//Renderer 2 print
            NSLog(@"Renderer 2 : %@",renderer2);

                renderer2.lineWidth = 7;
                renderer2.lineDashPattern = @[@20,@3];
                [renderer2 setNeedsDisplay];
                renderer2.path = (__bridge CGPathRef _Nullable)(self.myDottedPolyline);
                [renderer2 createPath];
                [renderer2 invalidatePath];
                renderer2.strokeColor = redRoute;


                if (_myDottedPolyline.isAccessibilityElement == FALSE)
                {
                   //Renderer 2 print 
                  NSLog(@"Renderer 2 Color: %@",renderer2);

                    renderer2.fillColor = redRoute;

                }

                return renderer2;

                //sets the pattern to a line 2 points long followed by a 1 point gap.
                //renderer.lineDashPattern = @[@2, @1];

        }
            return nil;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Assuming you want overlays for two king of types, I would have
>   controlled the overlay type with a BOOL property, if is lets say,
>   simple route add this overlay, if it is the advanced route add the
>   other overlay. [self.myPolyline class] and [self.myDottedPolyline
>   class] can be same class >> id.
>
> ```
> @property(nonatomic,assign) BOOL isDottedPolyline; 
>
>
>   -(MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
>     {
>        UIColor *BlueRoute = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:104/255.0f blue:163/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
>        UIColor *redRoute = [UIColor colorWithRed:241/255.0f green:122/255.0f blue:6/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
>
>
>         if (!self.isDottedPolyline)
>         {
>             MKPolylineRenderer *renderer1 = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc]initWithPolyline:overlay];
>
>                 NSLog(@"Renderer : %@",renderer1);
>                 renderer1.lineWidth = 5;
>                 renderer1.path = (__bridge CGPathRef _Nullable)(self.myPolyline);
>                 [renderer1 createPath];
>                 [renderer1 invalidatePath];
>                 [renderer1 setNeedsDisplay];
>                 renderer1.strokeColor = BlueRoute;
>
>                 if (_myPolyline.isAccessibilityElement == TRUE)
>                 {
>                     NSLog(@"Renderer Color : %@",renderer1);
>                     renderer1.fillColor = BlueRoute;
>                 }
>
>                 return renderer1;
>
>
>         }
>     else if(self.isDottedPolyline){
>
>             MKPolylineRenderer *renderer2 = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc]initWithPolyline:overlay];
> //Renderer 2 print
>             NSLog(@"Renderer 2 : %@",renderer2);
>
>                 renderer2.lineWidth = 7;
>                 renderer2.lineDashPattern = @[@20,@3];
>                 [renderer2 setNeedsDisplay];
>                 renderer2.path = (__bridge CGPathRef _Nullable)(self.myDottedPolyline);
>                 [renderer2 createPath];
>                 [renderer2 invalidatePath];
>                 renderer2.strokeColor = redRoute;
>
>
>                 if (_myDottedPolyline.isAccessibilityElement == FALSE)
>                 {
>                    //Renderer 2 print 
>                   NSLog(@"Renderer 2 Color: %@",renderer2);
>
>                     renderer2.fillColor = redRoute;
>
>                 }
>
>                 return renderer2;
>
>                 //sets the pattern to a line 2 points long followed by a 1 point gap.
>                 //renderer.lineDashPattern = @[@2, @1];
>
>         } else{
>             return nil; }
>     }
> ```

I assume you are using two MKPolylineRenderer for 2 different purposes using self.isDottedPolyline to  true when u want to create doted one and set it to false when you want to write the other one, between two anotation, and when u use

```
[self.geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        //  //NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
    if (I WANT DOTED POLYLINE)
       self. isDottedPolyline = YES;
    else
       self. isDottedPolyline = NO;

}
}];
```

u set self.isDottedPolyline it to true or false then poliline will be rendered on what you need, and as it goes to `-(MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay` it will see which one is true, doted or not.

Comment: can you plz refer above edit and suggest some change